# Separating an orbit and a point by neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Let $G$ be a group acting on the Hausdorff topological space $X$ discontinuously (meaning each orbit does not contain any limit point in $X$). Let $x,y\in X$ be two points that are not $G$ equivalent, meaning there is no $g\in G$ such that $g.x=y$. I wonder how to show the following:

> There exists open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$  and $V$ of $y$ such that $gU\cap V=\varnothing$ for all $g\in G$.

It is easy to see that we can find an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $G.x\cap V=\varnothing$. But I don't know how to continue.

Source: Iwaniec topics in classical automorphic forms, page 29.
[image]

Comment: You should clarify the definition of "discontinous". Do you really mean that orbits do not have limit points? See https://planetmath.org/discontinuousaction. Or do you mean "properly discontinuous"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I meant "each orbit does not contain any limit point in X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stuff from the picture is bad.

As I understood the definition, $\Gamma$ acts on $X$ transitively. This means that an orbit $\Gamma x=X$ for any point $x\in X$, see, for instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Types_of_actions). So each two points of $X$ are $\Gamma$-equivalent and all formal claims about not $\Gamma$-equivalent points of $X$ trivially true. :-)

The stability groups of points need not to be finite. For instance, let $X$ be any infinite discrete space and $\Gamma$ be a group of all bijections of the set $X$. Then $\Gamma$ acts on $X$ transitively and discontinuously, but all stability groups $\Gamma_x$, $x\in X$  are infinite.

If $X$ has no limit points in $X$ then each point of $X$ is isolated. This makes the claim “for any $x\in X$ there exists a small neighborhood $U\dots$” also trivial.

Trying to obtain non-trivial facts from the definitions, we can relax transitivity condition in the definition of a discontinuous action (as you did).

> There exists open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$  and $V$ of $y$ such that $gU\cap V=\varnothing$ for all $g\in G$.

But this is not necessarily true. For a counterexample for the claim it suffices in [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958230/group-acts-on-a-topological-space/1964226#comment4033049_1964226) provided by Moishe Kohan put $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$. Indeed, for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $A=\{1\}\times [0,\varepsilon)\subset U$. It is easy to see that $y\in\overline{GA}$.